# Repopulating values in Android Fragment onResume

Tags: java, android, replace, fragment

I have a Fragment(A) with a TextView with value "XXXX" set using setText() method. I replace Fragment(A) by Fragment(B) and then I replace B by A again.

When I do this, the value XXXX is gone in the Fragment(A) TextView.  I tried calling the TextView.setText method in the onStart as well as the onResume methods - same result.  When I debug the code, I can literally see that the setText method being used and the value XXXX is there. I printed it out on LogCat and it is there too, but I don't see any values on the screen.

I tried googling and I couldn't get an answer. I would appreciate any pointers.

**Code**

```
public void onResume() { 
  super.onResume(); 
  String dData = readFileFromSDCard(); 
  String dArray[] = dData.split(";"); 
  txtName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtName); 
  txtName.setText("first name")
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code, please.

Comment: I have this on my onResume:`code`
 public void onResume() {
  txtName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtName);
  txtName.setText("XXXX");
 }
This is how I replace:
DI di = new DI();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.topFrame, di);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
And this is my xml UI: `code`<TextView android:id="@+id/txtName" />`code`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With fragments you can't get the layout using `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtName);` you should do it like this. This is called when also when you replace fragment B back to A.

This code needs to stand in you Fragment class of course.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);        
    String driverData = readFileFromSDCard(); 
    String driverArray[] = driverData.split(";"); 
    txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName); 
    txtName.setText("Andrew");

}
```

Comment: Thank you. getView() instead of getActivity() did it.  Thanks again.